# How do I get CKEditor to run on my site's textareas?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Basically I was recently recommended CKEditor. My only problem is, I looked all over the site and have been looking on this one as well and cannot seem to find how to actually get the editor to convert my HTML textareas to the editor. I would like to accomplish this with the standard editor.

I have already looked at the support on http://ckeditor.com but couldn't find anything on how to use the editor for some reason.

If you could just show me a page that would explain how to do it or let me know in your comment that would be excellent!

**(Answer to question!)** Recently I encountered this issue with CKEditor, I was unable to get it to work. I could not locate a guide on how to use it correctly. To use CKEditor on your FTP Server just download the exact Editor you would like [here](http://ckeditor.com/download). Now locate the directory where your files were downloaded to. The file you need within the downloads folder should look something like this: ckeditor_4.2_standard.zip. Next, double click the folder ckeditor_4.2_standard.zip, then drag the CKeditor folder to the location where it will be easily accessible. Now all you need to do is upload the CKEditor folder you just moved to the root directory of your website via FTP.

Now, to convert your text areas into the new editor, just paste this code into the head of your HTML page:

```
<script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'Reply' );
};
</script>
```

(HTML tag within the body of your page)

```
<textarea class="Reply"></textarea>
```

Comment: It is surprisingly confusing, but http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed is probably what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first checkout the installation guide which will help you download everything you need.

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation

From here you can load it and edit it using these instructions:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_ckeditor_js_load

The basic syntax when creating the editor is to make a field like normal with a name:

```
<textarea name="editor1">&lt;p&gt;Initial value.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
```

and then initialize it by calling a replace of a current text area with the CKEditor:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
};
```